# Close webform modal and redirect to entity

Tags: 8, webforms

I have a webform that opens inside a modal. Everything works fine. Then I had the problem of closing the modal after the form was submitted. I fixed that to with the help of the following link: https://www.drupal.org/project/webform/issues/3002966#comment-12794056

I have a webform handler that creates a new entity in the `postSave()` method. After this entity is created, I want to close the modal and redirect to the entity detail page. What is the best/correct way to do this. I could use a `RedirectCommand` instead of the `CloseDialogCommand` but how do I get the entity id in the `_CUSTOM_MODULE_webform_submission_form_submit_ajax()` method. Using the AjaxResponse with a `RedirectCommand` in the `postSave()` method didn't work.

Any Suggestions would be great ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are so close!
just move the creation of the new entity from your postSave()
to right in the ajax call back

```
example:

_CUSTOM_MODULE_webform_submission_form_submit_ajax(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
 // At this point we have all access to $form_state->getValues();
 // the webform submission is all ready saved so we can use the values here.

 // Get the entity storage.
 $entity_storage = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStoage('ENITYNAME');

  // Create New entity.
  $new_entity = $entity_storage->create([
   'field_whatever' => $form_state->getValue('some_field');
  ]);
  // Save entity
  $new_entity->save();
  $new_entity_id = $new_entity->id();
  // set the url. 
  $url = "/where-ever/" . $new_entity_id;

  $response = new AjaxResponse();
  $response->addCommand(new CloseModalDialogCommand());
  $response->addCommand(new RedirectCommand($url);
  // Party.
 return $response;
}
```

Comment: Wow, I think that was too obvious :D Thanks for your help! That did the trick.